# Push a new version using git without losing the old one

Tags: git, bitbucket

I'm learning to use git and right now I have a project, I'm using bitbucket to keep my code and I know how to update it, the thing is that right now I made some mayor changes to my code and I want to upload it but without losing or updating the code already on bitbucket, how can I do that? I can't find the command.

Is a branch the same as a version? For example if I create a branch:

```
git checkout -b <new-branch>
```

this branch will be like say project v1.2?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git for beginners: The definitive practical guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/315911/git-for-beginners-the-definitive-practical-guide)

Answer (score 5):

There is no need to use branch for that.

Every time you do a commit, the corresponding version is stored in your repository. You can access it later via `git checkout` or bitbucket gui.

All you need to do is to add (`git add`) your files to repository, and then use `git commit -m "added support of this.."` to commit the current state of your code (all files you added).

After you make some changed to files, you do `git commit -m "fixed issue about ... "`, and this version will be also stored in history.

Note that commits are about (usually) small incremental changes in your code.
For release management and versions (`v.1.0`, `v.2.2` etc) you can use `tags`, as @Schwern suggested in comments below.

Comment: Commit messages are inappropriate for releases. Using them as such encourages large commits turning version control into just an incremental backup system. Plus you have to search the commit history to find releases. Commits should be for small changes, and commit messages should be describing why the change was done. For releases, [use tags](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Tagging). They annotate commits, are easy to list (`git tag -l`), and can be directly checked out (`git checkout v1.1`).

Comment: I definitely agree. I din't mean to use messages to mark releases, those are different story.  Let me change messages in my answer to be more precise.

Answer (score 1):

There are some standard you have to understand which developers are using.
Create a branch from master to develop and develop to yourBranch.

> Mater -> develop -> yourBranch

You Probably do changes in **yourBranch**, merge into develop, then develop to create release branch and merge in master, and create a new tag and push into production. This new tag will have all your change and old code also.

> V1.2(Tag) <- Mater(branch) <- releaseV1.2(branch) <- develop(branch)
>   <- yourBranch(branch)

## Tag Commands

```
# To get latest tag using command
git describe

# To create new tag
git tag v1.1

# To uploads all your tags in origin
git push --tags
```

## Branch Commands

```
# To create a new branch
git branch branchName

# To checkout in branch 
git checkout branchName

# Create a new branch and checkout in that branch
git checkout -b branchName

# To pull branch in origin
git pull origin branchName

# To add all files in which you have done changes
git add .

# To add single file in which you have done changes
git add pathToFile/fileName

# To commit your changes
git commit -m "Your message, what changes you have done"

# To push your changes in origin remote 
git push origin yourBranch
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you're asking for, you want to be able to update your project, but still allow people to download this version. You want people to be able to download v1.1 while working on v1.2.

In version control this is usually done with a [tag](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Tagging). A tag simply puts a label on a commit. It's kind of like a branch, but it never moves. Then people can checkout that tag. For example...

```
# This tags the current commit as v1.1
git tag v1.1

# This uploads your tags.
git push --tags

# Then anyone can checkout v1.1
git checkout v1.1
```

Using tags for releases allows anyone to easily checkout a release, and you can continue to commit small changes with good commit messages.

Here's [Bitbucket's own documentation about tagging](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/use-repository-tags-321860179.html).

Other systems like [Github go a step further and turn your tags into "releases" which are downloadable from their web site](https://help.github.com/articles/about-releases/). Bitbucket does not appear to support this feature, but [it seems it's in the works](https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issues/11404/bitbucket-equivalent-of-github-releases-bb).

---

As for branching, if v1.1 is *done* then there's no need to branch for a new release. Continue working on `master` and making new tags for new releases.

Where version branches are appropriate is for very large projects which have to maintain multiple major versions simultaneously. For example, a programming language might need to maintain v2 while working on v3 at the same time. So they might have a v2 branch and a v3 branch. Each would still have their own tags (v2.2.4, v3.0.3, etc...).